# MySQL select where value has multiple values in other rows

Tags: mysql, select, rows

First of all I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, I really tried searching but couldn't find on what I was looking for.

Okay so this is my table. I want to have a query where I select the user id's who have the same exact value more then 2 times.

```
| USER ID|COLOR|
---------|-------
| 1      | BLUE
| 2      | BLUE
| 3      | RED
| 4      | BLUE
```

So my query in this case would return

```
| USER ID|
|--------|
| 1      |
| 2      |
| 4      |
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to select the rows where `color` is repeated more than twice.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select color, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by color
     ) tt
     on tt.color = t.color and cnt > 2;
```

You asked for *more than 2* matches.  For 2 or more matches, you would use sgeddes's solution:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t tt
              where t.color = tt.color and t.userid <> tt.userid
             );
```

Or, if you just want the multiple ids:

```
select color, group_concat(userid)
from t
group by color
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: To add in, I'll be searching in a table with 140k rows. I want to get the user id's for people that have the exact same IP address. I'm gonna try this out now, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select userid
from yourtable t
where exists (
   select 1
   from yourtable t2
   where t.userid <> t2.userid and t.color = t2.color
)
```

Comment: The OP asked "more than 2 times", not "2 or more times".

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- excellent point, I didn't realize that when posting.  Your answer would handle >2, this would handle >1.  Assuming OP wants >2, I'll delete this response...

Comment: . . The OP seems confused.